# Triggering socket.io real-time notifications from Express 4 middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am building a real-time notification system using `socket.io`. This is my server-side code at the moment:

**`bin/www:`**

```
var app = require('../app');
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = app.io
io.attach(server);

server.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '...');
});
```

**`app.js:`**

```
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;
require('./config/socket')(app.io);
```

**`config/socket.js:`**

```
var User = require('../controllers/user');

module.exports = function (io) {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('Socket.io connected');
        socket.emit('connection', "Connection created.");
        socket.on('send notification', function(data) {
            User.createNotification(socket.request.user, data);
        });
    });
};
```

**`routes/index.js:`**

```
var express = require('express');
var User = require('../controllers/user');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/order', User.order);
module.exports = router;
```

**`controllers/user.js:`**

```
var User = require('../models/user').model;
var io = require('socket.io');

module.exports = {
    order: function(req, res) {
        /* some create order code */
        io.emit('send notification', 'Your order was successful!');
        res.sendStatus(200);
   }
}
```

I keep getting the error `TypeError: io.emit is not a function` whenever I try to call the route `POST /send` even though I am clearly initiating `socket.io` in my `app.js` and `bin/www` files and requiring it in `controllers/user.js`. All the examples I've seen online emit notifications from within this part:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit(event, msg);
    });
```

but I want my notifications to be triggered from the middleware so I can send custom notifications to the user when certain events happen in the application backend.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('xxx', function(obj){
        io.emit('xxx', {xxx: xxx})
    })
})
```

This should suppress your `TypeError:`.